# Stored procedure takes more than 30 seconds to execute

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I am optimizing the stored procedure in which I get list of more than 10K user ids in one table variable as a parameter. I am setting flag @ContainsUserIds if there is any data into the table variable. In main query selecting the all the users that are present in table variable or all the users if no data found in table variable (There are more condition in where clause).

The problem is here that the statement in where clause takes more than 30 second which has OR condition. If I removed the first condition to check @ContainsUserIds = 0 then it will execute within a second. Can someone please help me to optimize this query.

This Stored procedure is called from different position so the User ids may not pass.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [core].[spGetUsersByFilter]      
(      
  @ClientId                nvarchar(38)  = NULL,        
  @UserIds                 [UserIdList] readonly      
)      
AS      
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON         
      
    DECLARE @ContainsUserIds BIT = 0,
    SET @ContainsUserIds = CASE 
                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserIds) 
                                    THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 
                            END;   

    SELECT DISTINCT ES.Id
    FROM [db].[Users] E
    JOIN [db].[UserDetails] ES ON ES.UserId = E.Id 
    WHERE E.[Active] = 1  
         AND (@ContainsUserIds = 0 OR E.UserId IN(SELECT Item FROM @UserIds)) 
         AND ES.ClientId = @ClientId
END
```

Comment: If `@UserIds` contains many items, it is probably better to populate a temp table and join.

Comment: @Fildor But in where condition I am checking 2 conditions, how can we write this in join. If there is no any user Id passed as parameter then we go with the first condition else I am checking userIds in table variable

Comment: Try adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint and make sure Item is the primary key of the TVP.

Comment: Check type for Item in UserIdList - implicit conversions can be a performance hog in itself. Behind the OR check also for @ContainsUserIds = 1 to separate the subquery if not needed. Plus overall I would put the SET into a CTE part first (single row result) which can be used as CROSS JOIN. Eliminates the variable (aka parameter sniffing).

Comment: To troubleshoot this sort of thing, people often run the query from inside the stored procedure directly in SSMS, after right-clicking somewhere in the query and choosing Show Actual Execution Plan.  That execution plan most likely gives some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL notoriously dislikes `OR`, the optimizer sometimes works around it but in most cases it's a good idea to convert things to a `UNION [ALL]` syntax. If there's just 1 `OR` that's often easy to do, if there are multiple things explode fast.

Anyway, you could thus convert your stored procedure to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [core].[spGetUsersByFilter]      
(      
  @ClientId                nvarchar(38)  = NULL,        
  @UserIds                 [UserIdList] readonly      
)      
AS      
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON         
      
    DECLARE @ContainsUserIds BIT = 0,
    SET @ContainsUserIds = CASE 
                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @UserIds) 
                                    THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 
                            END;   

    SELECT DISTINCT ES.Id
    FROM [db].[Users] E
    JOIN [db].[UserDetails] ES ON ES.UserId = E.Id 
    WHERE E.[Active] = 1  
         AND (@ContainsUserIds = 0) 
         AND ES.ClientId = @ClientId
         
         
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DISTINCT ES.Id
    FROM [db].[Users] E
    JOIN [db].[UserDetails] ES ON ES.UserId = E.Id 
    WHERE E.[Active] = 1  
         AND (@ContainsUserIds = 1)
         AND E.UserId IN (SELECT Item FROM @UserIds)) 
         AND ES.ClientId = @ClientId
END
```

That said, you might just as well split things up here and do 2 separate `SELECT`s. Also, if the table-variable contains more than a couple of records you may prefer to use a temp-table as the latter allows for indexing and most importantly has statistics handling which WILL result in a better execution plan. I also prefer `JOIN` over `IN ()`, just make sure there are no doubled values when `JOIN`ing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [core].[spGetUsersByFilter]      
(      
  @ClientId                nvarchar(38)  = NULL,        
  @UserIds                 [UserIdList] readonly      
)      
AS      
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON         
    
    SELECT DISTINCT Item 
      INTO #UserIds
      FROM @UserIds
      
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BEGIN
            
            SELECT DISTINCT ES.Id
            FROM [db].[Users] E
            JOIN [db].[UserDetails] ES ON ES.UserId = E.Id 
            WHERE E.[Active] = 1                 
              AND ES.ClientId = @ClientId;
              
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq0_UserIds ON #UserIds ( Item ) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
            
            SELECT DISTINCT ES.Id
            FROM [db].[Users] E
            JOIN [db].[UserDetails] ES ON ES.UserId = E.Id 
            JOIN #UserIds T ON T.Item = E.UserId
            WHERE E.[Active] = 1  
                 AND ES.ClientId = @ClientId
        END
END
```

PS: all above written in notepad and untested, some assembly may be required =)

Comment: thanks for your solution. This is the perfect solution for my problem.